# Why my PC keeps display with the message CMOS Checksum error-Defaults Loaded if I unplug my pc?

Tags: desktop-computer

My PC keeps displaying the message CMOS Checksum Error - Defaults Loaded
every time I unplug the cables of PSU and Monitor. But, I do not unplug it, there's no message like that. Also, if I do not unplug those cables, I do not  wait for too long to power on my PC. But, if I unplug it, I have to wait for too long more or less 3 to 5 minutes so my pc will turn on, then a message or display "CMOS Checksum Error- Defaults Loaded"
What caused this problem? How can I fix this? Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

It's your CMOS battery fault. Time settings also went crazy, right? Settings are reflected back to default when you power off your PC as the battery can't hold them anymore. Changing your CMOS battery will solve the problem. :)